# Diffusion between 2 surfaces

Tags: surface-diffusion

Is the first time that  I am asking something here, so I apologize if it is not the place, or I am not clear enough.

I am working on this problem where I have a protein place between 2 surfaces (top and bottom). The protein is bound originally to the surface in the top (a membrane) and can diffuse in this surface with a diffusion coefficient Dt. However, when the protein gets in contact with the second surface in the bottom, the protein can bind to this surface and diffuses with a diffusion coefficient Db. Do you think that it is possible to estimate an effective diffusion coefficient for the protein? Or the lower motility will be the limiting factor? Db

[image]

Comment: Sure, but you will first need to know the rate at which the protein attaches to and detaches from the bottom surface (or some equivalent description).

Comment: Hi lemon , thank you for your  reply , I  know the rate to attaches and detaches from the bottom .

Answer (score 0):

If the protein attaches to the bottom surface at a rate $k$ and detaches at a rate $\nu$ then the probability of finding the protein attached to the bottom surface at any given moment is:

$$ P = \frac{\nu^{-1}}{k^{-1}+\nu^{-1}} $$

The mean diffusion coefficient is then just a weighted average:

$$ \langle D\rangle = PD_b + (1-P)D_t $$

You can see this to be true by computing the mean-square displacement over a time interval $k^{-1}+\nu^{-1}$, which I'll leave as an easy exercise.